# How to change "SelectOut "probability using the slider?

Tags: anylogic

How to change SelectOut probability using the slider in Anylogic?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the slider you do

```
slider.getValue()
```

You need to be sure that the minimum and maximum of the slider is set from 0 to 1 as minimum and maximum values.

You write slider.getValue() on the probability field of your select output block

Comment: Thank you for your help. The visual answer is always easier to follow, just like I posted.